# jQuery draggable dont fire mousedown on dragstop

Tags: jquery, svg

My draggable elements don't fire mousedown on drag end.
I have draggable img elements like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#1" ).draggable(
    { 
        scroll: true
    },
    { 
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
       $( "#1" ).addClass( "pinnedPin" );
       $( "#1" ).removeClass( "hiddenPin");

    }
}
);
})
```

I have also a svg map that is build of svg elements like:

```
<g>

<path id="map_39" fill="#2F71AE" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" d="M484.9,121.2c0.1-2.5-0.4-3.9-1.5-3.9H481v5.9l-0.6,2.899c1.5-0.3,2.5-0.5,3.199-0.899
                                c0.5-0.301,0.801-0.9,0.801-1.801C484.4,122.3,484.6,121.7,484.9,121.2z

                                "/>
 </g>
```

I have events on these svg elements like:

```
        },function(){
            $('#tip').hide();
            $('#'+id).css({'fill':map_config[id]['upcolor']});
        })
        //clicking effect
        _Textobj.mousedown(function(){
            $('#'+id).css({'fill':map_config[id]['downcolor']});
            alert("test");
        })
```

My problem is: when I drop draggable img it doesn't fire mousedown event on svg path below. When I click(mousedown) normally in element then alert("test") work as intended. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to "fix" this using coursorAt option to position cursor outside image. Then insted using mouse down, I used mouseup event.